# Import scipy on webserver online

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I'm running my python matplotlib script online. I have an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "heatmap.py", line 8, in &lt;module&gt;
    from scipy.stats.kde import gaussian_kde
ImportError: No module named scipy.stats.kde
```

I think that `scipy` is not found while importing. Is there any solution to this problem? How can i bypass this to get my script working?

Comment: Not to be too blatantly obvious, but have you installed `scipy` on the server?

Comment: @MattDMo that si exactly ma question. How can i install ti?

Comment: That completely depends on the server, what operating system it's running, whether you have admin access or not, etc. etc. I would suggest contacting the server's IT team and asking them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scipy was missing on my server, need to install it manually. Solved in this way.